# Using both MongoDB and MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am developing a new application that will be having a lot of assets, and the user traffic would be on the higher side, and I am thinking of using mysql for the user and the payment transaction data, and MongoDB for the rest of the other use-cases such as storing and retrieving assets, tags, etc.

I know my question is broad but may I know if it is a correct decision to use

1. MySQL for only user and payment transaction data
2. MongoDB for the rest of the use-cases.

Also, may I know if there are risks associated if I store user data and payment-related transaction data as well in MongoDB instead of MySQL.

Thanks,
Balaji.

Comment: Using 2 different databases is unusual and unnecessary complex

Comment: thanks for your comment :), please let me know if it is ok to use MongoDB for storing payment transaction data as well, if so then I won't be using MySQL.

Comment: Both are good databases. So you can store any data in both.

Comment: ok sure, thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: SQL databases like MySQL are really good then it comes to heavily relalated data with complex structures. NOSQL databases like MongoDB are really fast when it comes to simple data structures.

Comment: one more question please, can I restore the mongo db data easily from the backup incase of a crash, or the restoration is bit difficult ?

Comment: It is easy to restore mongoDB

Comment: @ juergen d,  if possible, please add it as an answer, so that I can mark it as accepted.